# Объединение файлов в консоли linux

Tags: linux, консоль, unix, putty

После команды:

```
cat kirlia hariyama > blitzle8_73
```

выдает ошибку:

```
cat: cannot open kirlia
cat: cannot open hariyama
```

Права доступа у юзера `rwx`.
Как решить проблему?

Comment: Не верю (с). `ls -l` в студию

Comment: да может просто файла нет. или там расширение  есть, а автор вопроса не увидел его

Comment: Покажите `ls -l`

Comment: Расширенные атрибуты смотреть. А может у вас ФС «навернулась», и её надо чинить.